# Passing variables between objects using constructor

Tags: php, variables, model-view-controller

I want to create a `$data` variable in **index.php**, then create a new controller (**ItemController**) which should put something in `$data` and pass it back to index.php (which is the front controller).

I'm doing this, but it doesn't work.

**ItemController.php**

```
<?php

class ItemController {
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function listItems() {
        $data = ['name' => 'James'];
        return 'templateName';
    }
}

?>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php

/* index.php is the front controller (something like a global controller
 * which routes all the requests to their relative controllers) */
require_once "controllers/ItemController.php";

// route the request internally
$uri1 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$data = Array();

if ($uri1 == '/sapienter/index.php') {
    $controller = new ItemController($data);

    $templateString = $controller->listItems();
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$data[name]');</script>";
    // This alert results empty, while I want it to output "James"
}

// Here I'll use the templateString to redirect to my template page.
?>
```

How can I do? I'm trying to do something like Java Spring's controller method:

```
private function methodName(Model model) {
    String name = "James";
    model.add(name);
    return "templateName";
}
```

Comment: Eisa Adil's answer is correct. Additionally: consider making your $data property private ( private $data; ) instead of public. Public means you can access the variable from outside the class aswell ( $controller->data[] = 'nonsense'; would work), which you probably don't want.

Comment: @DamienOvereem and what should I do to take `$data` in my **index.php** if `$data` is private? Should I put a getter method in my **ItemController** and call it with `$controller->getData()` ?

Comment: Yes, reason being that if you ever decide to change your class or the contents of the $data property, you can still make getData() return the same information, which then won't break your controllers. Although some people do things differently, I never allow direct access to my classes' properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `$this->data`. Because you are referring to a variable in the object. So the code should be

```
public function listItems() {
        $this->data = ['name' => 'James'];
        return 'templateName';
    }
```

Comment: So "alert('$data[name]')" should be alert('$controller->data[name]'). Or use getter ..